# Setting a value for a public variable from another class in php

Tags: php, oop

I am in a learning curve with PHP OOP

This is my code

**file1.php**

```
class A
{
    public $id;
    public $oop;

    function __construct(){
       $this->time=time();
    }

}
$a = new A();
```

I tried to access the variable `id` from a class B which is in another file, code given below.

**file2.php**

```
include('file1.php');

class B
{
    function store(){
        global $a; //question updated**
        $x = 1;
        $y = 1;    
    if($x == $y){
        $a->id = $y; // I am setting a value for variable id.
     }
    }
}

$b = new B();
```

Now I want to access the variable `id` in my index.php file as below.

**index.php**

```
require_once('file2.php');
$b->store(); // Store function executed ** question updated
echo $a->id;
```

The above code didn't throw me any error, the problem is the value I set for `$id` isn't echoing.

I also referred some of the answers from here which is nearly similar

[call variable from another function in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470428/php-call-variable-from-another-function-in-class)

[how to call a variable from one class function to another class function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217911/how-to-call-a-variable-from-one-class-function-to-another-class-function)

But didn't solve my problem.

Please, direct me to achieve my goal here.

Thank you.

Comment: "The above code didnt throw me any error" - it didn't? Then you should begin by setting up your development environment so that you will see syntax/parse errors and error/warning/notice messages. `public id;` - that's the first parse error. see also: error_reporting, error_log, display_errors, display_startup_errors at http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php (the last two solely for your development machine).

Comment: How does your B object get $a?

Comment: @VolkerK  I am assuming there is no syntax/parse error in the code I have provide and yes I have development environment is enabled to show  errors.

Comment: "I am assuming there is no syntax/parse error in the code I have provide" - As I've already pointed out `public id;` is the first syntax error in your code. There's a $ missing in front of id. So, check your setup again.

Comment: Thanks for showing me that typo. Actually in my script I have the $ for the variables. Now I have corrected in my question.

Comment: And now, [when calling `$b->store()`](https://3v4l.org/k7IPq), you should get the message `Warning: Creating default object from empty value`

Comment: @RyanVincent, Well I am executing $b-> store() in a process php file and I have updated my question with global variable although I have tried this and didn't work for me.

Comment: @RyanVincent, I have updated the question.

Comment: @RyanVincent, Yes, my development environment error reporting is set to 'E_ALL'.

Comment: setting error reporting to E_ALL is not enough: you have to actually tell the environment to *display* them as well `ini_set('display_errors',1);` at the top of the script

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

class A
{
    public $foo = 'bar';
}

class B
{
    public function mutateA(A $a)
    {
        $a->foo = 'qux';
    }
}

$a = new A;
echo $a->foo;

$b = new B;
$b->mutateA($a);
echo $a->foo;

// Outputs barqux
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following code..

file2.php - I think you forgot to call store method..

```
class B
{
    function store($a) //note the object passed
    {
        $x = 1;
        $y = 1;    
        if($x == $y)
        {
            $a->id = $y; // I am setting a value for variable id.
        }
    }
}
$b = new B();
$b->store($a); //You forgot to call store method
```

Comment: calling the method is not the solution I require.